# Nuxt 3: $pinia instance does not exist on nuxtApp when using defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp)

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

```json
Nuxt: 3.6.2
Pinia: 2.1.4
@pinia/nuxt: 0.4.11
```

While defining a Nuxt 3 plugin for Pinia I need to access the $pinia instance that exists on nuxtApp.

The `defineNuxtPlugin()` function passes on argument, the `nuxtApp`. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#creating-plugins

When I destructure `$pinia`from that argument (shown in pinia docs [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#nuxt-js))
I receive the following type error:[$pinia is of type unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwjZq.png)

But when I call `useNuxtApp()` to get `$pinia` within the `defineNuxtPlugin()` function, I have access to it.
[$pinia is available via useNuxtApp()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe0ii.png)

Any idea on why I the pinia example is not working for me?

So far I have followed the Nuxt 3 / Pinia installation guide as described as described here: https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

I use below code, to sum up is cast to Pinia type.

```
import { useMainStore } from '@/store';
import { Pinia } from 'pinia'; 

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ $pinia }) => {
    const _pinia = $pinia as Pinia;

    if (!_pinia) return;

   return {
        provide: {
            store: useMainStore(_pinia),
        },
    };
});
```